# Finding white rectangular areas in given image to increase OCR results

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, easyocr

Basically, I am trying to detect labels on boxes and these labels are white. Every label has own serial number and letter. I am using EasyOCR for detecting numbers and letters but sometimes EasyOCR can not detect texts accurate but If I take images from closer range, It detects very well. So, I need to crop label area with using image processing method. After that I will give it to EasyOCR to better results. I am open to any idea!

My Example Image:

[image: 1]

Comment: Threshold on brown box faces first. Then crop each box face. Now threshold on the white label. Then you should be able to use pytesseract to read the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the issue by cropping image based on image dimension with respect to the rack columns and rack rows. The code is,

```
import easyocr
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
h, w, _ = image.shape
rack_rows = 3
rack_cols = 3
total_boxes = []
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
for row in range(rack_rows):
    for col in range(rack_cols):
        # crop individual boxes based on dimension of image
        cropped_image = image[row*(int(h/3)) : ((row+1) * int(h/3)),(col*(int(w/3))) : ((col+1)* int(w/3)),:]
        # resize image based on custom size
        resize_image = cv2.resize(cropped_image,(800,800))
        # write cropped image to feed easyocr
        cv2.imwrite(f'image{row}_{col}.png',resize_image)
        # easyocr execution
        result = reader.readtext(f'image{row}_{col}.png')
        texts = [detection[1] for detection in result if detection[2] > 0.4]
        if len(texts[1])!=4:
            texts.pop(1)
        total_boxes.append(texts)

print(total_boxes)
```

Here I resized the image based on custom dimension (800,800) to feed easyocr after dimensional cropping. I haven't use any image preprocessing technique rather than resizer here. The output what I gained is,

```
[['S', '5607'], ['N', '4457'], ['U', '4017'], ['P', '4529'], ['X', '3311'], ['J', '2075'], ['W', '8075'], ['M', '9623'], ['K', '5412']]
```

Happy coding :)